# A famous 6 letter person

Tags: word, mastermind

Crack the code and name this famous person

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The famous person is...

> **GANDHI**!

We can deduce this as...

> LAUNCH - **A** is correct, **N** and **H** are misplaced.
>  SOWING - **I**, **N** and **G** are misplaced.
>  CAUGHT - **A** and **H** are correct,  **G** is misplaced.
>  LOCKER - GANDHI and LOCKER share no letters.
>  WANDER - **A**, **N** and **D** are correct.
>  ALUMNI - **I** is correct, **A** and **N** are misplaced.

> The most helpful way to get started on this was the combination of LOCKER and WANDER letting me know that 3/4 letters in WAND-- were in the right position and then I just ran through potential candidates until I got the right one.

Comment: That was fast. Well done!

Answer (score 15):

I'm impressed by @TakingNotes' speed... but I admit their solution feels a bit too magical for me.

Instead, I tried tackling the problem without a "dictionary", going purely by the clues.

> 1. Eliminate all letters in LOCKER.
>
>    Consider .AUGHT, WAND.., and A.UMNI:
>
>    - If A does not belong, then WND do, 3 of UGHT do, and 2 of UMI do. Even assuming maximum overlap (picking U), that's WND + U + 2 of GHT + 1 of MI, which is too many.
>
>      Thus A belongs, and is correctly placed in WAND...
>
>      The person we're looking for is ?A????.
>
>    Consider .AUN.H, S.WING, WAND.., and A.UMNI:
>
>    - If N does not belong, then WAD do, UH do, 2 of SIG do, and 2 of UMI do, which is too many.
>
>      Thus N belongs, and is correctly placed in WAND...
>
>      The person we're looking for is ?AN???.
>
>    Consider .AUN.H and A.UMNI. If U belongs, it's correctly placed in A.UMNI, and in .AUN.H, however A is already correctly placed in .AUN.H, thus U cannot be!
>
>    - Thus U doesn't belong.
>
>      Thus H belongs, though not in last position.
>
>      The person we're looking for is ?AN??? with H in place of a ?.
>
>    One of either M or I in A..MNI is in the correct position.
>
>    - If M is in the correct position, then D in WAND.. isn't and W is. H cannot be in last position, thus our word is WANDMH? and we are in a conundrum: from .A.GHT we need to pick G, for WANDHG, which conflicts with S.W.NG not allowing G in last.
>
>      Thus I belongs, and is in the correct position.
>
>      The person we're looking for is ?AN??I with H in place of a ?.
>
>    Consider .A.GHT: one of GHT must be in the correct position, and it's not T.
>
>    - If G is in the correct position, then D in WAND.. isn't and W is. But then H is in correct position too in .A.GHT!
>
>      Thus, H is in the correct position in .A.GHT.
>
>      The person we're looking for is ?AN?HI.
>
>    Consider S.WING, .A.GHT, and WAND..:
>
>    - Exactly 1 of SWG, 1 of GT, and 1 of WD must be selected for the 2 remaining spots.
>
>      Selecting W (in WD) means selecting T, forming WANTHI.
>
>      Selecting D (in WD) means selecting G, forming GANDHI.

And from there, we can use the clue (famous person) to resolve the puzzle.

> It's GANDHI !

Comment: Nice writeup walking through the entire logical process.

Comment: I second what Rubio said. Good job. +1